# How to put a block of writing in HTML from text-align: right

Tags: html, alignment, text-align

The title is slightly wordy so I will try to provide an example of what is happening in my code and what I want to happen.

**ONEDRIVE LINK OF ALL MY CODE**

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvauuVcN_DBAh30o-aOYmh2AMxL6?e=IL4csP

**I typed randomly on my keyboard for placeholder text**

---

**What is happening in output**

```
    Lorem Ipsum
daof esiogheagf difghea
fjaeiohrteg rearih
alfugeahoruij feioaryawrg
awirhyear rawirhy weri
fdsilryh ddfr

                                                                                             Lorem Ipsum
                     dioahef efyarw aspv9aru crupdjeamf zxpodruwa fopdurf sfjf fos rfps f idyrheajnr wafjhar
```

**What I want to happen**

```
    Lorem Ipsum
daof esiogheagf difghea
fjaeiohrteg rearih
alfugeahoruij feioaryawrg
awirhyear rawirhy weri
fdsilryh ddfr

                                                                                             Lorem Ipsum
                                                                                        saliaf saoie awsuor aswi
                                                                                              lary sfopea dpa fk
                                                                                         uwartyea fyisdr saor a
                                                                                           feaiory waro aorhf df
```

**Information**

```html
<p style="text-align: right">Education Perfect</p>
```

I have tried doing `style="width: -500px"`, didn't really seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enclosing your text in a container div and then reducing it's width?

```
<div class="container">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>more text</p>
</div>
```

And then:

```
.container {
  float: right;
  width: your-desired-width;
}

.container p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I can't give you an exact reproduction of the desired outcome since the HTML you posted is too vague, but that should do the trick.

Edit: re-read the question and updated the CSS rules accordingly, let me know if there's anything missing or if I'm getting the wrong idea.

Comment: Hi, really great answer however, is it meant to be so spaced between my ```<h3>``` and ```<div class="container">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>more text</p>
</div>```?

Comment: Sorry about the late answer. Can you share a snippet of your html and css or reproduce your code on codepen.io so I can take a look at it? It's hard to give any proper answer without looking at the code.

Comment: I've finished...?

Comment: Hey, seems I've missed your response. Could you be so kind to post your code here or elsewhere directly? I can't work with download links at the moment.